# Xubuntu 15.04 goes into sleep after powering up

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, power-management, shutdown, hibernate

Upgrade from Xubuntu 14.10 to 15.05 (Update history : 13.10 -> 14.04 -> 14.10 -> 15.04). The upgrading worked well. After rebooting the machine (Dell Inspiron 6000 - 10 years old) went automatically into sleep. Leaving sleep is easy but seems to be timed! (When you don't enter you password in a few seconds, it starts sleeping again). Once logged in, you can't power down the machine, it simply goes into sleep! The only way to go into powerdown is via "**sudo shutdown now**" command. Is there a way to fix this behaviour such that I become a normal powering up/down-behaviour? I already tries some of the xfce4-power management settings, but nothing seems to help (computer gives the logoin-screen again).

Some other oberservations. Even shutting down via the top-right button on the welcome-screen doens't succeed.

[image]